# Fixed space of the square of a symmetric matrix over $\mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, finite-fields

Let $M$ be an invertible symmetric $2n \times 2n$ matrix with entries in the finite field $\mathbb{F}_2$. Is $\mathrm{Ker}\ (M^2 - I_{2n})$ necessarily even dimensional?

Comment: Where does this come from? Looks a lot like homework.

Comment: It's not homework. If $A$ is a principally polarized abelian variety over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ of odd characteristic, is $A(\mathbb{F}_{q^2})[2]$ even dimensional?

Comment: There is a $4 \times 4$-matrix for which the dimension is odd.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: Thanks. Which one?

Comment: $\left(\begin{array}{clcr}1&1&0&0\\1&1&1&0\\0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&1 \end{array} \right).$

Comment: In this context $A$ must be in ${\rm Sp}_{2n}$, yes?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson, please post your comment as an answer (so the question no longer shows up as unanswered). Thanks (and well done)!

Comment: What if $M$ is alternating?

Comment: @DaveWitteMorris :Done. (Lisa- you are welcome).

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies (and darij). I just address the original question about symmetric matrices.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: Yes, you are right. I thought that the antisymmetry condition in characteristic $2$ simply translates to the matrix being symmetric. Did I make a mistake by forgetting that alternating $\neq$ antisymmetric in characteristic $2$? What is the concrete condition for $M$ to be in $\mathrm{Sp}_{2n}$? If you could answer my question in the comment, I would be most grateful.

Comment: The condition that $M$ be in ${\rm Sp}(2n,2)$ is that $M^{t}\left(\begin{array}{clcr} 0 & I_{n}\\I_{n} & 0 \end{array}\right)M = \left(\begin{array}{clcr} 0 & I_{n}\\I_{n} & 0 \end{array}\right).$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The matrix $M = \left(\begin{array}{clcr} 1&1&0&0\\1&1&1&0\\0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{array} \right)$ is an example where the dimension of the space in question is odd.

(Later edit: However if $M = M^{t}$ and also $M \in {\rm Sp}(2n,2),$ then we in fact have $M^{2} = I_{2n}$ as Darij Grinberg and Noam Elkies implicitly noted in comments).

Answer (score 5):

As Geoff Robinson has already said, the answer to the question is *no*.
In dimension $4$, there are in total $120$ counterexamples, of which
$96$ have kernel of dimension $1$, and $24$ have kernel of dimension $3$.
This can be found out e.g. with [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org) as follows:

```
gap> solutions := Filtered(AsList(GL(4,2)),
>                          M -> M = TransposedMat(M) and
>                               Length(NullspaceMat(M^2-One(M))) mod 2 = 1);;
gap> Length(solutions);
120
gap> Collected(List(solutions,M->Length(NullspaceMat(M^2-One(M)))));
[ [ 1, 96 ], [ 3, 24 ] ]
```

A list of these $120$ counterexamples is as follows (dots denote zeros):

```
. . . 1    1 . 1 .    1 . . .    1 . . .    . 1 . .    1 . . .    1 1 . 1    . 1 1 .  
. 1 1 1    . . 1 .    . . 1 .    . . 1 .    1 . . 1    . 1 1 1    1 . . 1    1 . . 1  
. 1 . 1    1 1 . .    . 1 1 1    . 1 . 1    . . 1 .    . 1 . .    . . . 1    1 . 1 .  
1 1 1 1    . . . 1    . . 1 1    . . 1 1    . 1 . 1    . 1 . 1    1 1 1 1    . 1 . .  

1 . . .    1 . . .    1 . . 1    1 . . 1    . 1 . .    1 . . 1    . 1 1 .    1 1 . .  
. . 1 1    . . 1 1    . 1 . .    . 1 . .    1 1 1 1    . 1 . .    1 1 . .    1 . . 1  
. 1 1 1    . 1 . .    . . . 1    . . . 1    . 1 . 1    . . 1 1    1 . . 1    . . 1 .  
. 1 1 .    . 1 . 1    1 . 1 .    1 . 1 1    . 1 1 1    1 . 1 1    . . 1 .    . 1 . .  

1 1 1 .    . 1 . .    . 1 . 1    1 . . 1    . 1 . .    . . 1 .    . 1 1 .    1 . . .  
1 1 . .    1 . 1 .    1 . 1 .    . . 1 .    1 1 1 .    . . 1 1    1 1 1 .    . 1 . 1  
1 . 1 .    . 1 1 .    . 1 1 .    . 1 . 1    . 1 1 .    1 1 . .    1 1 . .    . . . 1  
. . . 1    . . . 1    1 . . .    1 . 1 .    . . . 1    . 1 . 1    . . . 1    . 1 1 .  

1 . . .    1 . . .    . 1 . .    . 1 . 1    1 . 1 1    1 1 1 1    1 . 1 .    . 1 1 .  
. 1 . 1    . 1 1 .    1 1 . 1    1 . . 1    . 1 . .    1 . . .    . 1 . .    1 . . .  
. . . 1    . 1 1 1    . . 1 .    . . 1 .    1 . . .    1 . . 1    1 . 1 1    1 . 1 .  
. 1 1 1    . . 1 .    . 1 . 1    1 1 . 1    1 . . 1    1 . 1 1    . . 1 .    . . . 1  

1 . . .    1 1 . .    1 . 1 .    1 1 1 .    1 1 1 1    1 . 1 1    . 1 1 .    . 1 . .  
. 1 1 .    1 . 1 .    . . . 1    1 1 1 1    1 . 1 .    . . 1 .    1 1 1 .    1 . 1 .  
. 1 1 1    . 1 . .    1 . . 1    1 1 . .    1 1 1 .    1 1 1 1    1 1 1 1    . 1 . 1  
. . 1 1    . . . 1    . 1 1 .    . 1 . .    1 . . .    1 . 1 .    . . 1 .    . . 1 1  

. 1 . 1    . . 1 1    1 . 1 .    . . 1 1    . 1 . 1    1 1 1 .    . . . 1    . 1 . 1  
1 1 . 1    . 1 . .    . 1 . .    . 1 . .    1 1 . .    1 1 . .    . 1 . .    1 1 . .  
. . 1 .    1 . 1 .    1 . . 1    1 . . 1    . . 1 .    1 . . .    . . 1 1    . . . 1  
1 1 . .    1 . . .    . . 1 .    1 . 1 1    1 . . .    . . . 1    1 . 1 1    1 . 1 .  

. . 1 1    . . 1 .    . . . 1    . . 1 .    1 1 . 1    1 1 1 .    . 1 . 1    1 1 . .  
. . . 1    . 1 1 .    . 1 . 1    . 1 1 1    1 . . 1    1 . . .    1 . 1 .    1 . . 1  
1 . 1 1    1 1 1 .    . . 1 .    1 1 1 1    . . 1 .    1 . 1 .    . 1 . .    . . . 1  
1 1 1 1    . . . 1    1 1 . 1    . 1 1 .    1 1 . .    . . . 1    1 . . 1    . 1 1 .  

1 . 1 1    1 1 . 1    1 . 1 1    1 1 . 1    1 1 . 1    1 . 1 .    1 . 1 .    1 . . 1  
. 1 . .    1 . . .    . 1 . .    1 1 . .    1 1 . .    . 1 . .    . . 1 .    . . 1 1  
1 . 1 .    . . 1 .    1 . 1 .    . . 1 .    . . 1 .    1 . 1 1    1 1 1 .    . 1 . .  
1 . . 1    1 . . 1    1 . . .    1 . . 1    1 . . .    . . 1 1    . . . 1    1 1 . .  

. 1 . 1    1 1 1 .    1 1 . .    . 1 . .    1 . . .    . . 1 1    1 1 1 .    . 1 . 1  
1 . . .    1 . 1 .    1 1 . 1    1 1 1 1    . 1 . 1    . . . 1    1 . 1 .    1 . . .  
. . 1 1    1 1 1 1    . . 1 .    . 1 1 1    . . 1 1    1 . 1 .    1 1 . .    . . 1 .  
1 . 1 .    . . 1 .    . 1 . 1    . 1 1 .    . 1 1 1    1 1 . .    . . . 1    1 . . 1  

1 1 . 1    1 1 . .    . . 1 .    1 1 1 1    . 1 . .    1 . . .    1 . . .    1 . . 1  
1 1 1 1    1 1 . 1    . 1 . 1    1 1 . 1    1 . . 1    . . 1 1    . . 1 1    . 1 . 1  
. 1 . .    . . 1 .    1 . . 1    1 . . .    . . 1 1    . 1 1 .    . 1 . 1    . . 1 .  
1 1 . .    . 1 . .    . 1 1 .    1 1 . .    . 1 1 .    . 1 . .    . 1 1 1    1 1 . 1  

1 . . .    1 . . .    . . 1 1    . . . 1    . 1 1 .    1 1 1 1    1 . . .    1 1 . .  
. . . 1    . . . 1    . 1 . 1    . . 1 1    1 . 1 .    1 . . 1    . 1 1 1    1 1 1 .  
. . 1 1    . . 1 1    1 . . .    . 1 1 1    1 1 1 .    1 . . .    . 1 . 1    . 1 1 .  
. 1 1 .    . 1 1 1    1 1 . .    1 1 1 1    . . . 1    1 1 . 1    . 1 1 .    . . . 1  

1 . . .    1 . . .    . . 1 .    1 . 1 1    . 1 1 .    . . 1 .    . . 1 .    . . . 1  
. 1 1 1    . 1 1 1    . 1 . .    . 1 . .    1 1 . .    . 1 . .    . 1 1 .    . . 1 1  
. 1 1 .    . 1 1 .    1 . . 1    1 . . 1    1 . . .    1 . 1 1    1 1 . .    . 1 1 .  
. 1 . .    . 1 . 1    . . 1 1    1 . 1 .    . . . 1    . . 1 1    . . . 1    1 1 . .  

. . 1 1    . . 1 1    . 1 1 .    1 1 . .    . . . 1    1 1 1 1    . . . 1    . 1 . 1  
. 1 1 .    . 1 . .    1 . . .    1 1 1 .    . 1 . 1    1 1 1 .    . 1 1 .    1 1 1 1  
1 1 . .    1 . 1 1    1 . . 1    . 1 . .    . . 1 .    1 1 . .    . 1 . 1    . 1 . .  
1 . . .    1 . 1 .    . . 1 1    . . . 1    1 1 . .    1 . . .    1 . 1 .    1 1 . 1  

. . 1 1    . 1 . 1    . . 1 1    1 1 1 1    1 1 . .    1 . . 1    1 . 1 .    1 . 1 1  
. . 1 .    1 1 . 1    . . 1 .    1 . . .    1 . 1 .    . . . 1    . . 1 1    . . . 1  
1 1 . .    . . . 1    1 1 1 1    1 . 1 1    . 1 . 1    . . 1 .    1 1 . .    1 . . 1  
1 . . 1    1 1 1 1    1 . 1 1    1 . 1 .    . . 1 .    1 1 . 1    . 1 . .    1 1 1 1  

1 . . 1    1 . 1 .    . . 1 1    1 . . .    . 1 1 .    . . . 1    . . 1 .    . 1 1 .  
. . . 1    . 1 1 .    . 1 . .    . 1 1 .    1 . . 1    . 1 . .    . . 1 1    1 1 1 1  
. . 1 .    1 1 1 .    1 . . .    . 1 . 1    1 . . .    . . 1 1    1 1 1 1    1 1 1 .  
1 1 . .    . . . 1    1 . . 1    . . 1 .    . 1 . 1    1 . 1 .    . 1 1 1    . 1 . .
```

Comment: Quite a comprehensive answer! I just did mine my hand experiment- it didn't take long in this cae.